# Scanning in only words with scanner and a text file

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have to read in words from a file. For example a sentence might be

```
Bill's favorite animal is a dog. He is buying one at 1:30.
```

I need to only have the words, while not eliminating apostrophes, but eliminating the `1:30`. The desired out put for this would start:

- Bill's
- favorite
- animal,
- ...etc.

Code:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("[^\\w+]");
String word;

try{
    scanner=new Scanner(file);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Can't Find the File in Dictionary class!");
}
time=System.nanoTime();
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    scanner.useDelimiter(pattern);
    word=scanner.next();
    System.out.println(word);
    if(!word.equals("")){
        dictionary.add(word);
    }
}
```

I have tried using delimiter, but that results in `Bill` and `s` on separate lines with no `'`. I was hoping simply to be able to use

```
scanner.next(Pattern.compile("[^\\w+]));
```

but when I try that I get an InputMismatchException. Hopefully someone can help with this! Thanks!

Comment: You could pretty easily just split the string on spaces, but what defines what you need to remove? If 1:30 is not okay, is 1:1 not okay as well? What about just normal numbers, like 25, 30, etc? What about a timestamp? What about 04:04:14?

Comment: If apostrophes are allowed in words, why don't you just add them to the delimiter? BTW, \\w+ is wrong, the plus here is including a literal plus in the characters you will match.

Comment: Well it just needs to be Words. so never any numbers. but any punctuation aside from ' isn't acceptable.

Comment: Yeah David I was trying to figure out how to do that. This is what I ended up with in the delimiter: [\W&&[^\']]. Thanks for the tip on the + by the way.

Comment: I think `[\\W&&[^']]` is still going to leave you problems with underscores and digits. Also, I don't think that backslash would be correct before the apostrophe. It isn't a special character there, and you don't have to escape it. I think you would be including a literal backslash in what your subtracting from \W. I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Oh, unless it's really just a single backslash, but in that case you'd be escaping the apostrophe in a double-quoted Java string, which is also not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `"[^\\w+]"` is wrong. It is matching any character which is not a letter, digit, underscore, or a plus sign. The plus sign here is not a quantifier, so if your sample text contained "Bill got an A+" it would find the words "Bill", "got", "an", and "A+". Is this what you want? It seems more likely you meant to write `"[^\\w]+"`, which would eliminate the empty strings from the results when there is a run of delimiter characters.

It seems like you can just add the apostrophe to the pattern. If we also move the stray plus sign, that results in a pattern of `"[^\\w']+"`, however, while this is closer, it still includes digits so you will get "1" and "30" as words from "1:30".

I think what you really want is `"[^\\p{Alpha}']+"` which will use runs of one or more characters that are not letters or apostrophes as delimiters, and thus match all runs of letters and apostrophes as tokens. The output would be the following tokens:

- Bill's
- favorite
- animal
- is
- a
- dog
- He
- is
- buying
- one
- at